# Item at indexpath zero is not showing until the indexpath 0 is scrolled out of the screen

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview in each cell of a tableview by creating custom cell for the main tableview. The problem is i can see the tableview content for all the indexpath except for the first one. If i scroll the tableview to make the first cell out of screen and scroll the first cell back then the content in the first cell is showing.

Please find my code below

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [itemArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
    }
    for (int i=0; i<[itemArray count]; i++) {
        ////NSLog(@"row is %d",i);
        if (indexPath.row==i) {
            cell.textLabel.text=[itemArray objectAtIndex:i];
        }
    }
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why it is happening. I want the content of first cell to be seen on the screen also.

Comment: It's nearly impossible to answer `UITableView` questions without seeing your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: and numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Please check my code

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [itemArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
    }
    // why are you using this code in for loop ??
    /*
    for (int i=0; i<[itemArray count]; i++) {
        ////NSLog(@"row is %d",i);
        if (indexPath.row==i) {
            cell.textLabel.text=[itemArray objectAtIndex:i];
        }
    }
    */
    cell.textLabel.text=[itemArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update the below method as below. It may help you. And Please be sure You are reloading tableview after you add objects in `itemArray`.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
// add a placeholder cell while waiting on table data
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
    cell.textLabel.text=[[[DataManager GetInstance]getCurrentTableContent] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

return cell;
```

Comment: I have a table data in array before reloading data. I want to know how to solve the issue, if i scroll down and up then first cell's content is showing on the screen